# How to call a URL from an API

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on an API that receives and processes XML files. Currently, the API stores these files in a local folder and on Amazon AWS. One of the pieces of information I extract from these XML files is a URL. My goal is to automate the process of downloading a ZIP file from this URL.

Manually, the process would be as follows:

1.- Open the XML file.

2.- Locate the URL within the XML.

3.- Access the URL in a browser.

The URL opens a blank window that performs validations and triggers an automatic download of the ZIP file. I do not have the exact code that is triggered when opening the URL, as the URL is provided to me by an external company.

As mentioned earlier, I already successfully extract the URL. The closest I got to solving it was with this code:

```
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string xmlContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                // Parsear el XML para obtener el enlace dinámico
                XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
                string zipUrl = xmlDocument.Descendants("URL").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipUrl))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipUrl))
                        {
                            await _download.DownloadZipFiles(zipUrl, "archivo.zip");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            orderRepository.LogError(null, 422, "Ocurrio un error al ingresar a la url.", zipUrl);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Manejar cualquier error que pueda ocurrir al intentar abrir la URL
                        var errMsg = $"Error al abrir la URL: {ex.Message}";
                        orderRepository.LogError(null, 400, errMsg, cxmlFileName);
                        await IntentoDePedidoCorreo();
                        return FillResponse(payloadId, timestamp, "400", errMsg, errMsg);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var errMsg = "No se encontró la URL en el archivo XML.";
                    orderRepository.LogError(null, 400, errMsg, cxmlFileName);
                    await IntentoDePedidoCorreo();
                    return FillResponse(payloadId, timestamp, "400", errMsg, errMsg);
                }
            }
```

And there, this class is called:

```
public async Task DownloadZipFiles(string url, string fileName)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But that didn't work because it returned a damaged ZIP file. I converted it to HTML and saw that it was returning part of the HTML and JavaScript code from the page the URL was taking me to.

I'm developing my API in ASP.NET Core Web API, and I'm seeking guidance on how to automate this process. Is there any library or approach that would allow me to simulate accessing the URL? I would greatly appreciate any assistance or direction you can provide.

Comment: `"Is there any library or approach that would allow me to simulate accessing the URL?"` Did you mean, you would like to extract URL and then want to bind into the Zip file back? Apart from broken zip file everything is working as expected right?

Comment: Everything is working fine except for the URL. Essentially, I just want to automate the click on the URL through the API, replicating the same action as if I were to go into the XML and click on that URL.